Why are these two SQL queries returning different records?
I'm testing a few variations of a query to check which runs most efficiently. Most of the variations return the same number of records, but one doesn't, and I can't understand why. Can anyone help?
The purpose of the query is simply to identify the latest send records for each subscriber in a Business Unit.
Query 1:
SELECT top 250000
    sent.SubscriberKey,
    sent.EventDate as LatestSend
FROM
    ent._Sent as sent
WHERE 
    sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
    AND sent.EventDate = (
        SELECT MAX (latest.EventDate) 
        FROM ent._Sent as latest 
        WHERE latest.SubscriberKey = sent.SubscriberKey
    )
ORDER BY LatestSend ASC

Query 2:
SELECT top 250000
    sent.SubscriberKey,
    MAX(sent.EventDate) as LatestSend
FROM
    ent._Sent as sent
WHERE 
    sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
GROUP BY
    sent.SubscriberKey
ORDER BY LatestSend ASC

I expected these to return the same result set. However, query 2 returns approximately 3,000 more records than query 1. I can't figure out why those 3,000 records aren't being returned in query 1, as they seem to meet all the criteria.
EDIT: Thanks all for the suggestions. I've checked both query datasets and the source data, and there are no null values for EventDate or SubscriberKey, and no duplicates for SubscriberKey.
RESOLVED: Thank you all, the error was that I was missing the join on OYBAccountID in the subquery of query 1!

Duplicates perhaps. If two rows have same max eventDate, they will both be returned in query 1, which doesn't happen in Query 2

^ I was thinking the same. Are you sure Query 2 has more records, or is it Query 1? Typically if you select records for a specific (max) event date you can then see exactly what each record is returning - i.e. break it down, see the details of what you are returning under a microscope for one case.

I think, nulls in EventDate. Where condition sent.EventDate = (  SELECT MAX (EventDate) ...) for SubscriberKey

oh yeah, @ValNik that's better guess, because if it were duplicates, there should've been less records in query 2 not more

Shouldn't you order by DESC in conjunction with TOP if you want the latest dates?

Order by DESC or ASC may change result rowset, not rowcount?

Query 2 returns 1 row for sent.SubscriberKey. Query 1 may return 1 or more rows for sent.SubscriberKey. However query 2 returns approximately 3,000 more records than query 1. So query 1 returns only a part of sent.SubscriberKey and the difference here is only in the condition EventDate = MAX (EventDate) for SubscriberKey. I assume that the MAX (EventDate) for some SubscriberKey is null.

Thanks all. @siggemannen Definitely not duplicates, I've checked both result sets and there are no dupes in either.

@ValNik No nulls either, unless I'm misunderstanding something! Again, I've checked both resulting datasets and isolated several of the records missing from the second set, and they all have all fields populated

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks - but I've just run both queries ordering by DESC instead of ASC and both queries produce exactly the same results.

Probably because the query returns less than 250,000 records. Try to use a lower value for testing. E.g. TOP 20.

Try check null in EventDate, not SubscriberKey

@ValNik There are no nulls on EventDate either

You say in either dataset.. Do you check nulls in query results or in source data?

There are no nulls in the source data either, no.

Query 1:
SELECT top 250000
    sent.SubscriberKey,
    sent.EventDate as LatestSend
FROM
    ent._Sent as sent
WHERE 
    sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
    AND sent.EventDate = (
        SELECT MAX (latest.EventDate) 
        FROM ent._Sent as latest 
        WHERE latest.SubscriberKey = sent.SubscriberKey
    )
ORDER BY LatestSend ASC

This query is returning the top 250k rows from _Sent, where EventDate is the max EventDate for that SubscriberKey. Tied results per SubscriberKey will be returned as well, but only the top 25k of the whole set will be returned.
Furthermore, any SubscriberKey which has all null EventDate will be excluded.
You also appear to be missing an extra join condition in the subquery
        WHERE latest.SubscriberKey = sent.SubscriberKey
          AND latest.OYBAccountID = sent.OYBAccountID


Query 2:
SELECT top 250000
    sent.SubscriberKey,
    MAX(sent.EventDate) as LatestSend
FROM
    ent._Sent as sent
WHERE 
    sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
GROUP BY
    sent.SubscriberKey
ORDER BY LatestSend ASC

This query aggregates by SubscriberKey, returning the max EventDate but only the first 250k. Tied results per SubscriberKey are ignored, as it's just aggregating.
It will also not exclude nulls.

If you wanted the full row then you can use a row-numbering solution.
SELECT TOP (250000)
    sent.SubscriberKey,
    sent.EventDate as LatestSend
FROM (
    SELECT sent.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sent.SubscriberKey ORDER BY sent.EventDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ent._Sent as sent
    WHERE 
        sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
) AS sent
WHERE sent.rn = 1;

You can replace ROW_NUMBER with DENSE_RANK if you want tied results.

Thanks for your reply - just to clarify, both queries are returning the top 250k records, not 25k, and the result sets for both queries contain approx. 200k records. I included TOP (250000) to allow the sort.
I don't think tied results are the problem (if I understand you right), as there are 3k SubscriberKeys that are missing from the query 2 result set, despite them all having EventDate and matching OYBAccountID values. I'm happy enough to use a row-numbering solution but could you help me understand what's happening in my two queries?

Oh, and '[id]' is just me redacting my company's ID.

You are missing the OYBAccountID join condition.

@Charlieface Oh my gosh, THANK YOU, that's exactly it. Can't believe I missed that.

A cautionary tale:)

Try this debugging script perhaps:
SELECT  sent.SubscriberKey
,   sent.EventDate AS LatestSend
,   IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS ID
INTO    #t1
FROM    ent._Sent AS sent
WHERE   sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
AND sent.EventDate = (
        SELECT  MAX (latest.EventDate) 
        FROM    ent._Sent AS latest 
        WHERE   latest.SubscriberKey = sent.SubscriberKey
    )

SELECT  sent.SubscriberKey
,   MAX(sent.EventDate) AS LatestSend
,   IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS ID
INTO    #t2
FROM    ent._Sent AS sent
WHERE   sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
GROUP BY sent.SubscriberKey

SELECT  count(*) AS t1_count FROM #t1
SELECT  count(*) AS t2_count FROM #t2

SELECT  count(*) AS T1_count_distinct
FROM    (
    SELECT  DISTINCT subscriberkey, LatestSend
    FROM    #t1
    ) x
SELECT  count(*) AS T2_count_distinct
FROM    (
    SELECT  DISTINCT subscriberkey, LatestSend
    FROM    #t2
    ) x

SELECT  case when t.ID IS NULL THEN 'Missing t1' WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 'Missing t2' END
,   *
FROM    #t1 t
FULL JOIN #t2 t2
    ON  t2.SubscriberKey = t.SubscriberKey
    AND t2.LatestSend = t.LatestSend
WHERE   t.ID IS NULL OR t2.ID IS NULL

It gathers all data, and then does some count and other comparing. Finally, it displays all missing values from query1 and query2.

I guess, difference between queries is
SELECT top 250000
    sent.SubscriberKey,
    sent.EventDate as LatestSend
FROM
    ent._Sent as sent
WHERE 
    sent.OYBAccountID = '[id]'
    AND (
      sent.EventDate = (
        SELECT MAX (latest.EventDate) 
        FROM ent._Sent as latest 
        WHERE latest.SubscriberKey = sent.SubscriberKey)
      or (
        SELECT MAX (latest.EventDate) 
        FROM ent._Sent as latest 
        WHERE latest.SubscriberKey = sent.SubscriberKey) is null
     )
ORDER BY LatestSend ASC

So your Query2 is more suitable for the task.
